# How to use callback function in SilkTest's 4Test language

Tags: callback, automation, silktest

So I'm trying to use something ancient like the 4Test language in SilkTest in a somewhat modern manner.
I have several similar tests which differ in only a part of the code. I would like to create an infrastructure function which would do the boilerplate stuff and then just call different functions for different tests. Like a callback function let's say.

So I would like to do something like that:

```
testcase A(Function F)
    do some stuff
    F()
    do other stuff
```

Has anyone done this? How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found a solution and I'm posting it here for documentation reasons.

When a person wants to pass a function as an argument, they have to pass the name of the function as string, and then call it with the following structure

```
@(functionNameString)()
```

So the code would be like

```
void someFunction()
    Print("Hello World!")

@("someFunction")()
```

This also works with methods of objects.